# Understanding TCP's slow start

Tags: networking, tcp

I feel a little embarrassed to admit that I have trouble understanding TCP's slow start, which is supposed to be a very simple algorithm. Consider this scenario:

- sender has CWND=4 and sends all 4 segments
- receiver sends an ack for each received segment (it's not using any kind of delayed ack strategy)
- 4 acks quickly arrive at the sender side where they are queued in the sender's network buffer

  - sender processes ack 1, increments cwnd to 5, and sends 5 segments
  - sender processes ack 2, increments cwnd to 6, and sends 6 segments (total sent: 11)
  - sender processes ack 3, increments cwnd to 7, and sends 7 segments (total sent: 18)
  - sender processes ack 4, increments cwnd to 8, and sends 8 segments (total sent: 26)

Because the acks were queued in the sender's buffer the sender was able to send 26 segments while only having received an ack for 4 segments. This seems contrary to the intention of slow start of placing an upper bound on the sent traffic.

Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

#### Update

[RFC 2581](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2581) defines CWND as follows:

> At any given time, a TCP MUST NOT send data with a sequence number higher than the sum of the highest acknowledged sequence number and the minimum of cwnd and rwnd.

This confirms @jman's explanation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not computer programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cwnd` represents unacknowledged segments. So when the first ACK is received, `cwnd` becomes `5` and the stack sends `2` more segments since there are `3` unacknowledged segments in flight already.

Your example should read:

- sender processes ack 1, increments cwnd to 5, and sends 2 more segments (total sent: 6)
- sender processes ack 2, increments cwnd to 6, and sends 2 more segments (total sent: 8)
- sender processes ack 3, increments cwnd to 7, and sends 2 more segments (total sent: 10)
- sender processes ack 4, increments cwnd to 8, and sends 2 more segments (total sent: 12)

Comment: I have considered this interpretation. However, this means the "actual" window remains stuck at 2 segments. That seems wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate? "Window" is the number of unacknowledged packets in flight. That _is_ growing (=`cwnd`) with every ACK received.

Comment: I agree that the congestion window is actually growing exponentially. However, in practice the sender can only send small bursts of two segments each time.

Comment: The ACKs do arrive quite quickly. So its not really small bursts.